# Rescheduling a Timer in Java

Tags: java, android-studio, timertask

I have a Timer set up in my android project to act as a tempo flash. I would like this to be changeable because often people want to change the rate of a metronome when they are trying to play something. However, I am running into an issue that I cannot reschedule it. I have tried cancelling both the timer and the timer task however this gives me an Illegal State Exception saying that "Task already scheduled or cancelled". Is there a way to reschedule a TimerTask in a different timer, or possibly reschedule the Timer to have a different interval length, or do I have to use a different way to create a timer entirely?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The lifecycle of a `TimerTask` is linear: after you cancel it, it cannot be rescheduled. You have create a new `TimerTask`.

You can reuse the existing `Timer` - you don't have to cancel it.

Comment: So how would I solve the issue? Do I have to create a new TimerTask which will essentially be the same thing? Could I possibly create some kind of method which returns a TimerTask? Thank you though, that has cleared up confusion of why it's not working.

Comment: Edit the question to include the relevant parts of your code, it's easier to discuss something concrete than something abstract

Comment: But yes essentially you would create a new _instance_ of the same task (timer task is a class, right)